# Setting State with a parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Not sure what i'm tyring to do is possible, but

```
    state = {
    characters: [],
    planets: [],
    search: "",
    selectedCharacter: null
  };

componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchSomeData(
      "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/",
      "characters"
    );
    this.fetchSomeData("https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/location", "planets");
  }

  fetchSomeData = (url, stateToSet) => {
    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({
        [stateToSet]: data.results,
        next: data.info.next,
        prev: data.info.prev
      }))
      .catch(err => alert(err));
  };
```

I have a characters page, and a planets page both obviously 2 different endpoints from the api

https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/

https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/location/

the problem i'm having: 
when 
componentDidMount(){
}
runs it's fetching both sets of data, then storing both 
next page endpoints in the next state

```
"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/location/?page=2"
"https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/?page=2",
```

i need to access next when clicking a button to reload the next page of data. (one component displays characters, for that one i need the     "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/?page=2",
and one component displays planets for that one i need     "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/?page=2",
  )
how can i store these 2 separately?

i was thinking of trying to match them to their respective endpoints like this:

```
fetchSomeData = (url, stateToSet) => {
    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({
        [stateToSet]: data.results,
        **[stateToSet]next: data.info.next,**
        prev: data.info.prev
      }))
      .catch(err => alert(err));
  };
```

but i'm not sure you can incorporate the parameter into it like that.

Comment: check this once https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vkrag1 ? is this you need ? check the console once

Comment: Exactly what i was going for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change a small thing in `fetchSomeData` like below:

```
  fetchSomeData = (url, stateToSet) => {
    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({
        [stateToSet]: data.results,
        [`${stateToSet}-next`]: data.info.next,
        [`${stateToSet}-prev`]: data.info.prev
      }))
      .catch(err => alert(err));
  };
```

used [`${stateToSet}-next`] Template literals. Hope it helps and [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vkrag1)

This will print :

```
    {
     characters: Array[20], 
     characters-next: "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/?page=2"
     characters-prev: ""
     planets: Array[20], 
     planets-next: "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/location?page=2"
     planets-prev: ""
     search: "", 
     selectedCharacter: ""
  }
```

and @Croolsby's answer also nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
fetchSomeData = (url, stateToSet) => {
    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({
        [stateToSet]: {
          results: data.results,
          next: data.info.next,
          prev: data.info.prev
        }
      }))
      .catch(err => alert(err));
  };
```

Then you can access it like this:

```
this.state.characters.next
this.state.planets.next
```

The general lesson here is that you can have nested objects inside `this.state`.